# How to fix a function in R that doesn't work, but the code does

Tags: r

I have written a function to compute a dissimilarity matrix between 60 matrices, as shown below. `sentence1` is a list of the matrices and `result1` is an empty 60 x 60 matrix in which to load the results.

```
# to make code reproducible
library(dtw)
result1 <- matrix(, nrow = 60, ncol = 60)
for (a in 1:60){
    assign(paste(a, "1", sep="_"), matrix(runif(4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
}
sentence1 <- mget(ls(pattern="_1$"))

# function I wrote
comp_diss_matrix <- function(sentence, result){
    for (i in 1:60) {
        for (j in 1:60) {
            result[i, j] <- dtw(sentence[[i]], sentence[[j]], distance.only = TRUE)$normalizedDistance
        }
    }
}

comp_diss_matrix(sentence1, result1)
```

However, if I replace the variables in the function with the lists themselves, this works.

```
for (i in 1:60) {
  for (j in 1:60) {
     result1[i, j] <- dtw(sentence1[[i]], sentence1[[j]], distance.only = TRUE)$normalizedDistance
   }
}
```

What can I do to fix my function?

Comment: End the function with the object that should be returned, like `return(result1)` -- functions in R generally don't have side effects outside of them.

Comment: Don't use `assign`, especially since you are collecting all the objects with `mget`. Just build directly the list.

Comment: So when I use `return(result)`, it prints out the matrix, but the filled matrix doesn't appear in my objects window.

Comment: @nicola, do you mean to directly build a list like `sentence1 <- list(a, b, c)`? I have at least 360 items, so building lists directly would be time consuming. Is there another option?

Comment: It sounds like after you added the `return()` line to the function, you simply ran `comp_diss_matrix(sentence1, result1)` by itself, the result of which will be to print the output to the console. As mentioned before, R functions don't create objects unless you tell them to. If you want to run a function and save the output, you have to do so explicitly: `x <- comp_diss_matrix(sentence1, result1)`.

Comment: For avoiding `assign`, you're already creating the matrices in a for loop; there's absolutely no need to create individual objects. Create one empty list of the desired length, and then fill the list elements in the for loop. Other options would be to use tools like `lapply`.

Comment: An empty list of length 60: `empty_list <- vector(mode = "list",length = 60)`. Then assign something to each spot: `empty_list[[a]] <- my_stuff`.

Comment: using `result1 <- comp_diss_matrix(sentence1, result1)` worked wonderfully. thank you